# Is it possible to relate the same audio device in different APIs?

Tags: c#, audio, winmm, core-api

I'm using the winmm api to deal with audio. I'm using `waveInGetDeviceCaps` and `waveInMessage` to uniquely identify an "audio line". Everything works fine, except that in Vista, the name of the device is capped in 32 chars by the `WaveInCaps` struct.

To work around that, I'm envisioning using the core api when OS version is >= Vista. I'm using the `IMMDeviceEnumerator.GetDevice` and `IMMDeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints` to gather audio line information, but I'm not sure how to tell that one device under core api relates to one entry under the waveXx api.

I guess I could compare the device path of both, but that would go against MS's recommendation of treating the device path string as "opaque".

What would you say?

Comment: I think another way to help answering my question is: given an instance of IMMDevice, how do I know which "line index" (one that I can use as an argument for waveInOpen for example) is related to that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This scenario is described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370819(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Great! This will help me with other stuff as well, such as getting the guid of that specific endpoint.

Comment: What do you mean "guid of that endpoint"?  Do you mean the DSound GUID?  That's available in PKEY_AudioEndpoint_GUID.

You can also use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms790392.aspx DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACE and DRV_QUERYENDPOINTID to retrieve the endpoint ID for a given wave or mixer ID.

Comment: Right, which I already do for other reasons. The big picture here is the following: I'm developing a multimedia framework to capture sound based on the waveInXxx API. First I had to relate a given input line to its audio device (setupAPI), and for that I'm using the DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACE.
The problem I'm having with the waveInXxx api is that it truncates the device name under Vista, so I'm appealing to direct sound to get that full name.

Comment: @Larry: I think I'm closer to a solution. I wasn't able to find `DRV_QUERYENDPOINTID` anywhere, but using waveInMessage with `DRV_QUERYSTRINGID` I was able to get a bit closer to what I want. I got the following string from it
*00000001:00000037:{0.0.1.00000000}.{54d2b8ce-17da-4324-ac30-e8a1003ab430}:widMessage:00000000*
and the following string from IMMDevice.GetID:
*{0.0.1.00000000}.{f1821ba1-3c39-49fb-9f5b-d3d9a85cffe8}*
I could compare the strings right now, but it'd be better if there's another message that would bring strings in similar formats and I could treat them as opaque.

Comment: @Han: do you know where `DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID is` declared?

Comment: Bah... sorry about that. I was using an old WinDDK. I think I'm good now.

Comment: Padu: Sorry, I got the wrong symbol, QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID is the right symbol.

Comment: No problems, I got it. Do you think the result the resulting string from this function is reliable? I mean... will it work under all platforms so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <mmddk.h>

WCHAR szBuffer[256]
uiDeviceID = 0;
messageId = DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID;
waveInMessage((HWAVEIN)IntToPtr(uiDeviceID), messageId, szBuffer, 256);
```

Then I get the guid as same as IMMDevice apis. Nice!