# Is there any way to obtain an audio device's GUID using only the waveIn API?

Tags: c#, guid, directsound, winmm

The reason why I ask this is because I want to relate a given winmm audio device like the ones you open using waveInOpen with a directSound device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to this question can be derived from an answer I got from another question I asked here:

[Clicky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929658/is-it-possible-to-relate-the-same-audio-device-in-different-apis)