# Where is DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID declared?

Tags: c#, audio, winmm

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929658/is-it-possible-to-relate-the-same-audio-device-in-different-apis) one.

I need to use the winmm function waveInMessage using the above mentioned constant. I can find a bunch of similar defines (such as `DRV_QUERYDEVICEINTERFACE`) in the mmddk.h, but the pair `DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEID` and `DRV_QUERYFUNCTIONINSTANCEIDSIZE` is not. 
They are mentioned in the MSDN document entitled ["Device Roles for Legacy Windows Multimedia Applications"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370819(VS.85).aspx), which makes no reference to header files used in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <mmddk.h>
```

What compiler are you using?

- Download the latest Platform SDK for Windows if you're using VC++.
- In case of, e.g MinGW, new headers should be available.

I bet your problem is related to old header files.

Comment: Thanks! I was using an old SDK... I was able to find it on the WinDDK 6001.18001

Comment: -1 mmddk.h is *not* in the PlatformSDK.  Padu Merloti's *comment* is correct about it being in the WinDDK.